# Windows Xp Autoenrollment Issue

Tags: windows-xp, certificate-authority

i've trouble to auto enroll for Xp Clients.
I setup up an two tier ca on windows 2012 and configured Autoenrollment.
So far i just have been testing with Windows 7 Client and i have no issue at all. I receive a certificate within seconds.

But know i wanted to test this for XP Clients but couldn't get the certificate.

Event Log shows Id 13.

But testing with certutil -ping i get an error.
certutil -ping on Windows 7 Clients is successful.

I already tried this but i have all
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6711baa0-bff5-402d-8baf-a57e2d3ec876/problem-with-autoenrollment-of-a-windows-2003-server-to-a-windows-2008-ca-server

normal ping is successful for xp so it's not a network problem

So i get first event id 17 source:autoenrollment and then because ca is not available event id 13.

Does anyone has a hint for me because i have no idea.

Comment: Do you really need a solution for an OS that is obsolete in April?

Comment: depends on what customer wants, i just want to be prepared because i know there still a lot of guys within my company who use xp.  I rather would skip this part and work on something more usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP is pretty limited in the Certificate encryption methods it can use, from win2k8 on ward those same methods are depricated and from 2k8r2 unsupported. trough some hacks it is possible to enable these again. however as mailq said, your best bet is upgrading to vista or higher for those XP boxes.

Comment: Yes i known that this is not the best combination. but i tried to make root cert and sub cert compatibly with xp client by taking sha1 and other things. now Xp won't even talk with my ca, that is frustrating